# centos auto kill process after a given timeout in a given directory

Tags: bash, process, centos, sh, kill

I want to make a script - `bash` - shell script (I don't know very well what is need it) to `CentOS` (VM for my Apache server) and kill all processes that running on a specified folder (and subfolder of them) after a given timeout.
can anybody help me with this?

for example here i want to kill after timeout all processes in folder users.

```
# ps -fC java
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     27549     1  0 Apr18 ?        09:21:48 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager
root     29060 27549  1 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
root     29161 27549  5 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
root     29176 27549  5 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
root     29186 27549  5 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
root     29206 27549 12 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
root     29216 27549 12 23:25 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld
```

Comment: What do you mean "running on a specified folder"? Did `cratimeout` not do what you wanted for some reason?

Comment: for example...i will have some processes running on opt/apache tomcat/
and i will have some other processes running on opt/apache tomcat/bin..
and i will kill processes only from on folder...not all java processes!
cratimeout maybe is ok...but i had not found the way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean started from there? Do you mean the binary is in those directories? Do you mean processing files in those directories? How do you intend to check/detect this "running on a specified folder" condition?

Comment: started from there. ps if you write : ps -fC java you will see all java processes that are running on your VM and where.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach (to set a `timeout` when you launch the process) is more correct and in general safer than to create a script to search for the active processes. Even more if there are other similar processes that have to remain alive.

If you have `GNU` utils installed in your system you can use `timeout`. Try from the shell prompt

`date ; timeout 2 sleep 10 ; date`

and you will see that the process sleep is killed after 2 seconds. If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then it exits with status 124.  Otherwise, it exits with the status of COMMAND. (see `man timeout` or `info coreutils timeout` for full reference. Note that by default time is in seconds.)

If you have not installed the GNU utils you can either install them or use `expect` with a similar syntax.

If you still want to challenge with a research and kill script, you have to be sure about the selection rules for the process that will go to be `kill`ed. You can start also from `ps aux | grep YOURPATTERN |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` to obtain a list of PID on which you can operate...

`YOURPATTERN` is where you will put your selection rule, the `grep -v grep` is to exclude the process of grep itself, in `awk` you can specify a command too (e.g `awk '{print "kill "$1}'`) and pipe the output to a shell...

Comment: thanks for your answer..but what i have to do for kill with timeout procceses that running on- starting from a specified folder ? and not kill all my running processes...furthermore i want to kill only java processes...

Comment: The problem is that a java process can spawn other java processes. You should not know in advance how and when this will happens. Please post in your question (not here) a typical output of your `ps -fC java`. After maybe compare it with `top  -bc -n 1 | grep java` and `top  -bc -H -n 1 | grep java`. With the 1st you'll see only few process and maybe the ones you want to kill, with the 2nd command you'll see all the threads (`-H`). A lot more. Which ones do you want to kill? And how can you know in advance? This was the _selection rule_ that you had to write in the script.

Comment: By the way, If you want to kill all _java process_ it's enough to write `pkill java`. It will  kill all java process that you can see e.g. with `pgrep -l java `. (with `-` or `--signal` you can specify even the signal to send to each matched process).

Comment: For one more time...i want to kill processes that started for a specified folder ONLY.i do not want to kill all java processes. furthermore i had update my question as you want...

Comment: Quick and dirty (unsafe) If you want to select all java process with the pattern "`/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld`" you can do at your own risk `ps -fC java | grep -e "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/users/test/HelloWorld " | awk '{print "kill "$2} | /bin/sh`. Why it is unsafe: because if there is another script that has the same pattern (maybe like parameter) you will kill it too. 
`

Comment: ok...and how i will make it autokilling that processes with timout... please write me a full code if you can..

Comment: Add the command `timeout 30m` in the same line before the command that  you use to run your program: in this way you force a timeout of 30 minutes to the program.

Comment: Simple example: write from a shell `sleep 10`. The program _sleep_ will wait 10 seconds and after will finish. Now write `timeout 2 sleep 10`. The command _sleep_ want still to _"sleep"_ 10 seconds, but after 2 the command timeout will kill it.